# Nested synchronous loops in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, nested, synchronous

So I have an array of object that I want to use for my server, each object has the same amount of keys.

Here is a simplified version of the array:

```js
[{
  "BTQ": 1,
  "COLLIC": "Foo1",
  "MMC": "Bar1",
  "PTURE": 39,
  "STOCK": 6,
},
{
  "BTQ": 1,
  "COLLIC": "Foo1",
  "MMC": "Bar2"",
  "PTURE": 31,
  "STOCK": 2,
},
{
  "BTQ": 2,
  "COLLIC": "Something1",
  "MMC": "AnotherThing1",
  "PTURE": 40,
  "STOCK": 5,
},
{
  "BTQ": 2,
  "COLLIC": "Something1",
  "MMC": "AnotherThing1",
  "PTURE": 11,
  "STOCK": 7,
}]
```

and I want to build a function that loops through all of these objects, and builds another JSON array that looks like that:

```js
[
  {
    "BTQ": 1,
    "COLLICs": {
      "Foo1": {
        "Bar1": {
          "Stock": 6,
          "PTURE" {"39": 6}
        },
        "Bar2": {
          "Stock": 2,
          "PTURE": {"31": 2,}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "BTQ": 2,
    "COLLICs": {
      "Something1": {
        "AnotherThing1": {
          "Stock": 12,
          "PTURE": {"40": 5, "11": 7}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  //etc ...
]
```

I am using NodeJS, and I figured out I needed to build a function like this one :

```js
function step(i){
  if (i < raw.length){
    data.push(raw[i].A);
    step(i + 1);
  } else {
    console.log("Finished");
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

but the thing is I don't know how to nest this function...
Here is what I want to achieve in the end:

1) Loop through each object in the raw array (done with the function above)

2) For each object, loop through data (the sorted array) and see if any of the objects in there has the same "BTQ" value, if so : go into the object, and see if the `raw[i].COLLIC` exists the `data[j].COOLLICs`' keys. If exists, look if the MMC exists, ETC ... If any of the values does not exist, create a new key/object which stores all the informations, and then start again with the following raw object.

It is probably not very clear and I'm sorry for that, if it can help, I had built the same algorithm but with for loops, I can paste it here if it could help to make things clearer.

I really hope you can help me because I'm loosing my mind on this ... 
Thanks ! Ali

Comment: "for loops in Node are async" is not true.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "for loops are async". One of the main characteristics of for loops is that they are *not* asynchronous.

Comment: What `for loop` are you using? A normal for loop is NOT async

Comment: Yeah i know, i just couldn't explain it better... the fact that i'm using nested for loops in the program to modify an array for example, and that the rogram goes beyond this for loops and executes the other functions/instructions that are in the same scope as the loop, without waiting for the loop to end

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows the loops i was using : https://jsfiddle.net/qg3j8463/1/

Comment: _"the rogram goes beyond this for loops and executes the other functions/instructions that are in the same scope as the loop"_ -- ?? If you don't want other functions to be called, simply don't call them? -- PS: Don't use `var`, use `const`or `let`... and may I say _what a mess_ (JSFiddle code)... :-(

Comment: i need them to be called, but only when the loop is finished

Comment: Then call them when the loop is finished. If you don't like how you wrote the code, why did you write it that way..? :-) But I'd clean it all up before anything else. Make it more modular, not that one giant nested loop "blob" of a code.

Comment: I did, then saw it didn't work the way i wanted it to work, so i came here to ask for some advice on how to make it work :-)